# Macro to find and format all endnotes in a Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, footnote

I wonder if there is a way to find all the endnote references in a Word document, select them, and format them with a style en masse? The same for endnote text: find all endnote text, select, format with a style en masse.

I am thinking of perhaps a macro along these lines: [How do I format all hyperlinks in a Word document?](https://superuser.com/questions/1252571/how-do-i-format-all-hyperlinks-in-a-word-document)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a lovely contributor at MS Answer, I think I've found a solution without using a macro and instead using the far simpler Find and Replace function.

See Suzanne S. Barnhill's answer here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/my-footnotes-have-lost-their-superscript/602c9cfa-2ea4-4c25-ac8b-98b83f22297c

> It may be that you just need to reapply the style. You can do this
> using the Replace dialog.
>
> 1. With the insertion point in the document body (not a note), press
>    Ctrl+H to open the Replace dialog.
> 2. In the "Find what" box, type ^f (for footnote reference marks) or ^e
>    (for endnote reference marks).
> 3. Click More to expand the dialog.
> 4. With the insertion point in the empty "Replace with" box, click
>    Format, then Style.
> 5. Select the Footnote Reference or Endnote Reference style, as
>    appropriate, and click OK.
> 6. Click Replace All.
>
> Word should search the entire main story (document body) and then
> search the notes. If the problem is only with reference marks in the
> notes, you can start there.

Thank you, @Viki Ji, for your input.

Comment: I am gald to hear that your issue has been resolved. Hope to have a nice week~

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to select one of the endnotes, and go to *Home>Select>Select all Text With Similar Formatting* to select all the endnote text, and then format them with a certain style.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. Sadly, I tried that before posting, but it didn’t work. It wouldn’t select all. I can find each reference with ^02, however.