# How do I change the color and remove the underline of all hyperlinks in a Word document *without* changing the font, italization, etc.?

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink, styles

I have a very long document (a book) that I wrote collaboratively in Google Docs. Bringing it into Word, [this great explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/1252571/how-do-i-format-all-hyperlinks-in-a-word-document?newreg=be42e441691b433fae950ab70379c164) gets me most of the way to where I want to go. **But** it strips out the underlying font, any bold or italization, etc.

How can I just change the color and remove the underline of all the hyperlinks w/o changing anything else?

Thanks so very much!!

Comment: Change the hyperlink style? Use a new style?

Comment: Or, if you want to *remove* all hyperlinks, select the whole document, right-click on one link, and select remove hyperlink. It would be a bit deceptive to *leave* the links, if they're effectively invisible, i.e., the same as the body text.

Comment: Maybe a search-replace can work, [as explained here](https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2019/03/30/word-find-and-replace-a-custom-font-colour/)

Answer (score 2):

This way :

- In the Home pane, Styles group, click the small icon on the bottom-right
  of the group
- In the drop down menu, click *Hyperlink > Modify…*
- In the Modify window, click on the blue color and choose your
  preferred color from the drop-down menu
- Click the blue Underline button so it becomes less blue
- Click OK and close the Styles pane.

Comment: Thanks! But when I do this, at least in Word 2016 for Windows, it undoes the formattng of anything that isn't "normal" text. E.g., it strips out a different font, italization, etc. Don't know why -- your suggestion seems like it should work...

Comment: It wouldn't work if the document doesn't use the Hyperlink style, but does things manually (font, color etc). Could you post online a very small example document?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot, I'd use the Style Inspector to check the content updated with the hyperlink style when the content isn't a hyperlink. That might give you a clue as to what's going on and how to remedy it. FYI, you can use Find/Replace to apply styles.

SUsan H.